# Press [Enter] with SWTBot Keystrokes on Windows

Tags: windows, line-breaks, keystroke, swtbot

I have a problem with the automation of pressing the `[Enter]` key using SWTBot. The use case is opening a "date chooser" widget, selecting a date and pressing `[Enter]` to confirm. While sending a line-feed (LF) worked well on Linux, it failed on Windows. Also a second try of sending carriage-return plus line-feed did not work on Windows (but worked on Linux):

```
import org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.keyboard.Keystrokes;

// first attempt did not work on Windows:
dateChooser.keyboard().pressShortcut(Keystrokes.LF);

// second attempt also did not work on Windows
dateChooser.keyboard().pressShortcut(Keystrokes.CR, Keystrokes.LF);
```

Any advice on how to simulate pressing `[Enter]`on Windows would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting, for us  `text.pressShortcut(SWT.CR, SWT.LF);` worked well both on Windows and Linux. Try to use not Keystrokes.*, but org.eclipse.swt.SWT. Or maybe it's your control limitation - try to click some "execute" button if you have one

Comment: Do you use a virtual machine or something like that? We had issues with keystrokes on windows too (in virtual machines). We now use a real machine that has a keyboard plugged in and it works since.